# VBA - Copy Cell from Sheet into Outlook email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am new to VBA and have created the following code that sends an email. 
My question is how do i copy some cells from my excel sheet that I am currently using to be pasted inside the excel file?

Thanks,

```
 Sub CIR_Save_Email()

 Dim objoutlook As Object
 Set objoutlook = CreateObject("outlook.application")

 Dim objemail As Object
 Set objemail = objoutlook.createitem(olmailitem)
 Const olFormatHTML As Long = 2

 emailbodymessage = "<HTML><BODY>Hi Team," & _
 "<br><br>Attached is the Display's CIR for today<br><br>" & _
 "<b>Brief overview of CIR</b><br><br>" & _
 "<b>Purpose:</b> To get a snapshot of what your current inventory levels by SKU are every day." & _
 "<ul style=""list-style-type:circle"">" & _
   "<li><b>Unrestricted QTY</b> The total inventory at that DC (i.e.Deliveries Created + Available Qty)</li>" & _
  "<li><b>Deliveries Created:</b> Orders that are being processing at that DC (i.e. they will NOT be included in Available Inventory)</li>" & _
   "<li><b>Available:</b> How many cases are available to use at that DC </li>" & _
   "<li><b>Avail DOS:</b> How many DOS the available cases equate to</li>" & _
 "<li><b>IT QTY:</b> How man cases are in transit</li>" & _
 "<li><b>Avail +IT DOS:</b> How many DOS the available cases equate to</li>" & _
 "</ul> </body> </html>"

 emailbodymessage2 = "<html><body><ul style=""list-style-type:circle"">" & _
 "<li><b>Future Available:</b> The total DOS of cases Avail + IT</li>" & _
 "<li><b>QI QTY:</b> How many cases are on Qualitiy (ie Non-Conformance)</li>" & _
 "<li><b>Blocked QTY:</b> How many cases are blocked from ordering due to damages, short dating, expired, etc." & _
"<li><b>CM- months:</b> The forecasts of the months past (CM-1=July)</li>" & _
 "<li><b>% to Fcst:</b> How much of your projected forecast has shipped this month</li>" & _
 "<li><b>Current SNAP Fcst:</b> This month's projected forecast</li>" & _
"<li><b>CM+ months:</b> The forecasts of the months moving forward (CM+1= September)</li>" & _
 "</ul> </body></html>"

 With objemail
     .To = emaillist
       .cc = ""
     .Subject = "Display's CIR " & Date
     .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML '// 2
 .HTMLBody = emailbodymessage & emailbodymessage2 

 .display

 End With

 End Sub
```

Comment: Are you asking how to insert some additional content inside the email body?  BTW your two HTML segments each have complete open/close tags (ie each one is a full HTML  "page") - you only need one set of opening and one set of closing `html` and `body` tags)

Comment: Yes i am trying find out how do I add copied cells from a worksheet into the body of the message. 

Thanks for the input on the HTML tags!

Comment: You will need to explain a little more exactly what you need to include: a whole range? how large? Or just individual values?  Where in the mail does it need to go?

Comment: Hi Tim, 

I want to copy a excel table that spans across multiple cells, for arguements sake, lets say A1:C5. I would like to put this below my text. 

Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function (internally uses exporting range into HTML) to convert excel range into html. Then resultant HTML should be included into your generated HTML body.

The function is exporting `Range` into HTML temporary created file and then strips content to only div (without surrounding HTML tags).

However, I'm not sure if formatting and other details will fit your requirements. Other solution is to construct HTML from cells manually, but it is much more work.

Usage: `str = GetHtml("Sheet1","D4:E6")`

```
Public Function GetHtml(ByVal sheetName As String, ByVal rangeName As String) As String
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim fileName As String
Dim txtStream As TextStream
Dim html As String
Dim line As String
Dim readLines As Boolean

Set fso = New FileSystemObject

 Dim rng As range
 fileName = fso.GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\" & Replace(fso.GetTempName, ".tmp", ".html")
 If fso.FileExists(fileName) Then
    fso.DeleteFile fileName
 End If

 Set rng = Sheets(sheetName).range(rangeName)

 ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSourceRange, fileName:=fileName, Sheet:=rng.Worksheet.Name, Source:=rng.Address, HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic).Publish
 Set txtStream = fso.OpenTextFile(fileName, ForReading, False)

 readLines = False
 html = ""
 Do While Not txtStream.AtEndOfStream
    line = txtStream.ReadLine
    If InStr(line, "<!--START OF OUTPUT FROM EXCEL PUBLISH AS WEB PAGE WIZARD") > 0 Then
        readLines = True
    End If
    If readLines Then
        html = html & vbCrLf & line
    End If
    If readLines And InStr(line, "<!--END OF OUTPUT FROM EXCEL PUBLISH AS WEB PAGE WIZARD") > 0 Then
        readLines = False
    End If
 Loop
 txtStream.Close
 Set txtStream = Nothing

 If fso.FileExists(fileName) Then
    fso.DeleteFile fileName
 End If
 Set fso = Nothing

 GetHtml = html

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you want to 'copy some cells from my excel sheet that I am currently using to be pasted inside the excel file'.  I think you man copy from Excel and paste into the body of an Email, right.

```
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Don't forget to copy the function RangetoHTML in the module.
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a fixed range if you want
    'Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").Range("D4:D12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "ron@debruin.nl"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm